# How to remove whitespaces from string in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I've been trying to join two tables 'A' and 'B' using a column say 'Col1'. The problem I'm facing is that the data coming in both columns are in different format. For example : 'A - Air' is coming as 'A-Air', 'B - Air' is coming as 'B-Air' etc.

Therefore, I'm trying to remove white spaces from data coming in Col1 in A but i'm not able to remove it using any function given in AWS documentation. I've tried Trim and replace, but they wont work in this case. This might be achieved using regular expressions but i'm not able to find how. Below is the snippet of how I tried using regex but didn't work.

```
select Col1, regexp_replace( Col1, '@.*\\.( )$') 
from A  
WHERE
    date = TO_DATE('2020/08/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
limit 5
```

Please let me know how can I possibly remove the spaces from a string using regular expressions or any other possible means in Redshift.

Comment: `regexp_replace(Col1, '\s+', '')` should do it

Comment: Thanks for replying but this didn't work, 'A - Air' still coming as 'A - Air' with spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Col1, regexp_replace( Col1,'\\s','')
```

This worked for me.